# How could I get rid of the blank in this case?

Tags: floats

I use the following code to generate two page with two figs per page.

```
% get on left side of a 2-page spread
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\mbox{}\clearpage\fi

% two images on this page
\includegraphics{f1}

\vspace{...}
\includegraphics{f2}

\clearpage

% two more images on this page
\includegraphics{f3}

\vspace{...}
\includegraphics{f4}

 % caption
\vspace{...}
\captionof{figure}{........}

\clearpage
```

But the paper would looks like:

> Paragraph A...
>   A lot of blank....
>   two page of four figures
>   Paragraph B...

How could I let Paragraph B follow Paragraph A and get rid of the blank area?

Comment: Where is `Paragraph A` in your code snippet?

Comment: @Werner, Hi, Paragraph A is a short paragraph which follow the above text since you know, I am writhing a paper using Latex and the template of a journal.

Comment: Your images are not floats. When you use plain `\includegraphics` the image does not become a float. Therefore, the sequence of items appear in the same way as in your `tex` file. How do you wish to display the figures? 2 images with a common caption? Or a caption for each of them?

Comment: @remus, hi, thank you for your comment. I have to arrange my figures as follows, Four figure share a caption, each figure has a subcation.

Comment: @remus, I just edit some text as the subcation. For example, (a) 1/4 figure   (b)  1/4 figure...

Comment: What template do you use for your journal?

Comment: @remus, a small template from the journal I try to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create floats in order to get the desired behavior regarding text and figure placements. Here is a minimal working example that makes 2 floats, each with 2 figures. If the figures are large enough, they will be split on 2 pages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

Paragraph A

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A subfigure}
        \label{fig:sub1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A subfigure}
        \label{fig:sub2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A subfigure}
        \label{fig:sub21}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A subfigure}
        \label{fig:sub22}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A figure with two subfigures}
    \label{fig:test2}
\end{figure}

Paragraph B


\end{document}
```

Comment: ,Hi, when I try to use the first working example, the third and four figs always hide. Please see the question. Since I need to cite the figures, so the first is best for me. Thank you.

Comment: That happens because the 4 figures do not fit on a single page. So the 2nd working example should work for you. I will erase the first example from the answer.

Comment: I erased one example from the answer. Please use the example that's in the answer right now.